# logout con tokens en angularjs

Tags: angularjs, tokens

El problema está en el botón logout (salir) de la app, pues en google chrome tengo que hacer click dos veces a este para ejecutar con éxito el logout y en los otros navegadores con un click ya se ejecuta.

Estoy utilizando TOKENS para las sesiones.El método ejecutado cuando hacemos click sobre el botón logout es el que muestro a continuación que a su vez llama a otro método `removeAllTokens()` que contiene dos métodos `save()` y `clear()`:

El método clear elimina todos los tokens de la lista.

Por lo que veo si yo comento el método `clear()` que esta dentro de `removeAllTokens()` el logout se hace correctamente clickando solo una vez en el botón logout pero si no está comentado es necesario clickar dos veces en google chrome creo el problema está en el método `clear()` que elimina los tokens de un array que contiene los tokens pero no entiendo bien lo que hace el código del método `clear()`.

```
clear() {
        for (let i=this.tokens.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
            if (this.tokens[i]) {
                var token;
                if (this.tokens[i].isValid) {
                    token = angular.extend({}, this.tokens[i].token);
                }
                this.remove(this.tokens[i]); // remove the token
                if (token) {
                    oauthState.notifyInvalidToken(token);
                }
            }
        }

        this.tokens = [];

        for (let i =0; i<this.reservedSlots; i++) {
            this.tokens.push(undefined);
        }
    }

save(): boolean {
        return storage.set(config.name, this.tokens.filter((t) => t && t.isValid).map((t) => t.token ));
    }

removeAllTokens() {
   clear();
   save();
}

logout() {
        let token = this.token.rcs().token;
        this.token.removeAllTokens();

        let redirect = () => {
            oauthState.config.logoutRedirect && window.location.replace(oauthState.config.logoutRedirect);
        };

        let redirect1 = () => {
            alert("error");
        };

        this.$http
            .post(`${oauthState.config.baseAuthUrl}/${oauthState.config.revokePath}`, {token: token.accessToken}, {withCredentials: true})
            .then(redirect, redirect1);
    }
```

Se que es complicado dar una respuesta satisfactoria con apenas este código que muestro pero no lo puedo publicar todo porque es código privado de trabajo.

Por lo menos me gustaría entender cual es el proceso que se utiliza para hacer logout utilizando tokens ya que no entiendo bien el proceso.

Answer (score 0):

yo lo cambiaria por esto:

```
   logout() {
    var token = this.token.rcs().token; //aca estas copiando por referencia puesto que es un objecto lo que asignas, si deseas que sea una copia independiente usa angula.copy().

    let redirect = () => {
        this.token.removeAllTokens(); //Entiendo que token.accessToken es donde reside el token que deseas desautorizar
        oauthState.config.logoutRedirect && window.location.replace(oauthState.config.logoutRedirect);
    };

    let redirect1 = () => {
        alert("error");
    };

    this.$http
        .post(`${oauthState.config.baseAuthUrl}/${oauthState.config.revokePath}`, {token: token.accessToken}, {withCredentials: true})
        .then(redirect, redirect1);
}
```